# Which commands operate on a single item and which take an array of objects?

Tags: powershell, pipeline, powershell-4.0

I've been trying to learn PowerShell and am currently looking at piping the output of one command into the input of another.  I've found that some commands can operate on an array of items that are piped in while other commands can only operate on a single item in an array.

For example, `Where-Object` can operate on an array of items, returning a subset of them, whereas `New-Item` can only operate on a single item.

I have to handle the two types of commands differently, with commands that can only operate on a single item having to be enclosed in a `ForEach-Object` block.

For intance, `Where-Object` doesn't need a `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-Service | where Status -eq "Stopped"
```

But `New-Item` does:

```
@("Red", "Blue", "Green") | foreach {new-item -Name $_ -ItemType directory}
```

How can I determine whether a particular command can act on an array of items, or whether it can only act on a single item?

As far as I can see the help doesn't really give a clue.  For example the help for `Where-Object` states the input type is `System.Management.Automation.PSObject`, which doesn't imply to me it can be an array of objects.

**EDIT:** aljodAv has pointed out in his answer that `ForEach-Object` is not actually needed in the second example.  It can be written as:

```
@("Red", "Blue", "Green") | new-item -Name {$_} -ItemType directory
```

The question still stands, however, as $_ represents the current item from the collection object passed through the pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this is a matter of which can accept an array and which can't, this is more an issue of what cmdlets accept piped input, and which don't, and for the ones that do accept it, how do they use the objects piped into them. For the most part you will want to look at the help for whatever cmdlet you are interested in to see if it accepts piped input.

Now, `Where-Object` is designed to work on an array of objects piped into it, so it doesn't specifically state that it does, and assumes that the user is going to be able to figure that out. `New-Item` actually does take an array of objects to be piped into it, but the parameter that accepts that is the `-Value` parameter, so that may be a bit less useful for most people. Your example above shows that you want to specify the `-Name` parameter, which does not accept piped values.

So the answer to your question is that anything that accepts piped input will allow you to pipe an array of the correct object type into it and it will process each item in turn, the challenge can be in finding if or how an object will accept piped information.

For your specific example, I personally think that `New-Item` should have accepted piped strings to accommodate the creation of either directories or empty files, or allow piped objects/hashtables to allow for the creation of more complex things.

Comment: Does that mean `Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue)` in the help for a parameter of a command would indicate that parameter would accept piped values?

Comment: Yes, it does, but the object that you feed it has to have the appropriately named value to match that parameter.

Comment: Sorry if I seem pedantic but I'm trying to understand: Does a parameter that accepts pipeline input by value, as opposed to by property name, still need to match the name of the object value being received from the pipeline?

Comment: If it takes values by pipeline then it usually either is a cmdlet for a specific purpose (i.e. `Set-Content` sets the content of a file, and can be piped that content), or the value is an object that is manipulated by the cmdlet and the piped data is not for a specific parameter, but will be worked with as a whole by the cmdlet (i.e. `Add-Member` can be piped PSCustomObjects and will add members to the object).

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand now, thanks.  `New-Item` would write the whole of the object from the pipeline to a file as its contents, hence `-Value` accepting the whole piped object.  But `-Name` doesn't use the whole object at once, it needs to operate on each item from the piped object separately, so it can't accept piped objects.

Answer (score 1):

> But New-Item does:
>
> `@("Red", "Blue", "Green") | foreach {new-item -Name $_ -ItemType directory}`

No, it's not true that New-Item requires `ForEach-object`.
See how:

`'Red', 'Blue', 'Green'|ni -Name{$_} -ItemType directory -whatif`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I guess `{$_}` has the same effect as `foreach{...$_...}`.  In both cases `$_` represents a single item in the collection object passed through the pipeline.  Is that correct?

Comment: It's part of the PowerShell syntax. Yes, $_ represents the pipelined object (if the parameter accepts pipeline input)..